# Which one of these is/are correct?

Tags: subjunctives

I mean, if any is right:

> The least you could have done is have won.
>
> The least you could have done is won.
>
> The least you could have done was won.
>
> The least you could have done was win.
>
> The least you could have done was had won.
>
> The least you could have done was have won.

Also, could you teach me how to use this kind of structure? Just a simple explanation would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only correct one is

> The least you could have done was won.

*could have* is talking about the past and *was* is past tense, so it's the only correct one.

This one

> The least you could have done was have won.

while maybe a correct sentence, just does not flow naturally. No need for the last have.

Just remember that *was* should be used when talking about the past. *Is* should be used when talking about the present or future. For example *"The test is going to be hard on Monday."* is talking about the future. And *"The house is blue with a pink door."* is present tense.